# Area under a curve with two functions given

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area of the region bounded by the curve and line in the diagram

I've found the upper function to be ($-x + 6$) and the lower function is ($x^2+4$)

I did $-x + 6 = x^2 + 4 $ to get the upper and lower. a = 1 b = -2

$$
\int_{-2}^1 (-x + 6) - (x^2 +4) dx
$$

Would like to know if this is correct.

[Graph / Diagram given by the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDd2Q.png)

Comment: Yes it seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

In general the area between two curves, say $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, on an interval $[a,b]$ is given by $$\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-g(x)|dx$$

Since $f(x)=-x+6\geq x^2+4=g(x)$ for $x\in[-2,1]$, then $|f(x)-g(x)|=f(x)-g(x).$

Thus we have $$
\int_{-2}^1 |(-x + 6) - (x^2 +4)| dx
=\int_{-2}^{1}(-x+6)-(x^2+4)dx=\frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: Would like to ask another question, how do we know which function is going to be the f(x) / top function ?, do I need to sketch a graph to check? or is there any other way to check. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $|f(x)-g(x)|=|g(x)-f(x)|$, so it doesn't matter which function you choose first. If you can sketch a graph then it's easily visible where $f(x)-g(x)\geq 0$ so that $|f(x)-g(x)|=f(x)-g(x).$ Otherwise in this case we have $f(x)-g(x)=-x+6-x^2-4=-x^2-x+2=-(x^2+x-2)=-(x+2)(x-1),$ and we want where$f(x)-g(x)\geq 0$ or $(x+2)(x-1)\leq 0$ which is satisfied if $x+2$ is negative and $x-1$ is positive OR if $x+2$ is positive and $x-1$ is negative. Clearly this is the case for $x\in[-2,1]$.

Comment: If instead we have $g(x)-f(x)=x^2+4+x-6=x^2+x-2=(x+2)(x-1),$ then for $x\in [-2,1]$ we obtain that $g(x)-f(x)\leq 0,$ so $|g(x)-f(x)|=f(x)-g(x)$ and we continue as before. See [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/areabetweencurves.aspx) for more.